# RMagick looses transparency when saving gifs

Tags: ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, rmagick

I am trying to wite a Ruby script for batch processing images with RMagick. But when I use for exaple this code:

```
img = ImageList.new('in.gif').first
pixels = img.get_pixels(0,0,img.columns,img.rows)
img.store_pixels(0,0, img.columns, img.rows, pixels)
img.write('out.gif');
```

I expect my image stay unchanged, but it looses it's transperency turning it into black. How do I correctly process gifs with transparency with RMagick?

EDIT:
Here is my image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lPWn.gif

If it's usefull the virsion I used are:
Rmagick gem - 2.13.2
Ruby - 2.1.2
ImageMagick 6.7.7-10
Ubuntu 13.10

EDIT2:
I found that this actually doesn't occur for all my images but rather for that exactly image and other of this small size. Maybe something is wrong with processing small gifs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it's really a bug in ImageMagick itself. I don't know if it's fixed in 6.8, it was easier for me to just convert my images to png. With png it works fine. The bug is related to editing small like 16x16 gif images with transparency.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this only with the code you posted. HAve you tried to run it in isolation? Anyway, you should be able to override the default background color this way:

```
img.background_color = 'transparent'
```

full code:

```
img = ImageList.new('in.gif').first
img.background_color = 'transparent'
pixels = img.get_pixels(0,0,img.columns,img.rows)
img.store_pixels(0,0, img.columns, img.rows, pixels)
img.write('out.gif')
```

you can also try to override it on the `ImageList` itself:

```
img_list = ImageList.new('in.gif')
img_list.background_color = 'transparent'
img = img_list.first
pixels = img.get_pixels(0,0,img.columns,img.rows)
img.store_pixels(0,0, img.columns, img.rows, pixels)
img.write('out.gif')
```

Comment: Neither of your code changes anything. I updated the question to add my image. Maybe with it's reproducable? The background of an icon turns to black. How do I run it in isolation?

Comment: I am using `ImageMagick 6.8.8-9`, maybe try to upgrade?

Comment: What OS are you using? Your version seems to be very new as it doesn't appear in Ubuntu 13.10 repo. Installing it is a lot of pain. Does RMagick requires so new release to work properly?

Comment: I am running OS X and installed ImageMagick via Homebrew. Tried to install an older version but no luck, sorry. Normally I would think that this should be detected fairly quickly, should it be a bug in imagemagick.